# How to set marker with route-me

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, route-me

I want to set a Marker (PNG) to a specific location on the map (based on x/y coordinates).
I know how to do that in Xcode, but I have to do it with Visual Studio (C#/Xamarin).

Thank you so much for telling me the syntax!

https://www.xamarin.com/
https://www.github.com/route-me/route-me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible without major modifications.

But if you actually manage to compile route-me into a stand-alone native library, you'd also be required to make C# wrapper around it, invoking all the respective functions.

Once you've done this, you'll be able to properly use it within Xamarin.

All in all, you're better off using the built-in Map control, and tweak it however you may wish. Adding PNGs on specific coordinates is a trivial task with the MKMapView.